# Cursor and Database doesn't get closed android

Tags: android

Good day, i have this problem with my sqlite database on a widget application, it never gets closed even when i explicitly call it. i get this logcat error

```
02-26 00:49:42.070: E/Database(18049): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

and for some reason, when i get a cursor and call the getCount() method, it always increments with the last value also added. for example.. if i get cursor and the getCount() method returns a value of 5 from a column and i later remove the widget. when i add the widget again and query a different column which i know has a value of 6, i instead get 11 as the return value from the cursor. getCount() method. its like the cursor and the database never closes. any ideas what could be wrong?..

method:

```
private void setTag(String tag){
WeatherImageDB weatherimagedb = new WeatherImageDB(this); // get logcat error on this line
        weatherimagedb.open();

        ArrayList<String> image_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        image_list.clear();

            if(weatherimagedb.open() != null){
            Cursor cursor = weatherimagedb.retrieveTag(tag);
            Log.d(TAG, "size is " + cursor.getCount()); // this always gets incremented with also the last value added

             if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    image_list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tag)));
                    //System.out.println("imagelisted!!");
                }       
                while(cursor.moveToNext());

                }

                //do other stuffs here with arraylist and then clear

            }
            image_list.clear();
            cursor.close();
            weatherimagedb.close();

        }
```

and code in database class:

```
    private final Context mcontext;
    private DBHelper dbhelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public WeatherImageDB(Context context){
        mcontext = context;
        dbhelper = new DBHelper(mcontext);
    }

    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DBHelper(Context context){
            super(context, IMAGE_DB, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS imagetags");
            onCreate(db);   
        }       
    }


    public WeatherImageDB open() throws SQLException {
        try{
            db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        return this;

    }

    public void close(){
        Log.d(TAG, "calling close on Database Object here");
        if(dbhelper != null){
        dbhelper.close();
        db.close();
        }
    }

    public long tagImage(String pathname, ContentValues val){   
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, val);    
    }

    public boolean deleteTag(String entry ){
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null) >0;
    }

    public Cursor retrieveTag(String tag){
        //open();
        String[] condition = {tag};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, condition, null, null, null, null, null);      
        return cursor;
    }

}
```

Comment: anyone has an idea please? its not crashing my application but i would like to remove all bugs.. i hope i explained my problem clearly.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the cursor that you declared will be inside if loop only....I think there might be some other global object with same name as "cursor"...

```
if(weatherimagedb.open() != null){
    Cursor cursor = weatherimagedb.retrieveTag(tag);
    //some stuff--> make sure there are no return statements in this part.
      //If any return statement  exists close   the cursor and then execute return

    //it should be closed here
    cursor.close(); 
}
//You are closing outside if loop which is holding reference of some other cursor
cursor.close();
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. i close the cursor within the if statement but its still giving the trouble. what exactly you mean by global object with regard to this. do you mean in the application or within the activity/services?

Comment: In the sample code what you gave the cursor is being closed out side the if loop...But the cursor is declared inside if loop.This says that the cursor you are closing outside the if loop is not the one that is being declared inside if loop...

Comment: oops see your point there, oversight from my part. Thanks for pointing that out.